# Include the templated Control into template?

Tags: c#, silverlight, templates, controltemplate

I want to template a Control and include the Control itself into the template, not only the control's content.

For example, I have a button:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <Button Name="hello" Content="123" Width="100" Height="100" >
        </Button>

</Grid>
```

I want to make a broader to surround this button, so it will look like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="120" Height="120">

        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue"/>
        <Button Name="hello"  Content="123" Width="100" Height="100" >
        </Button>

</Grid>
```

But I want to make this more genric, not only for button, but for some other control.
i.e Image, TreeViewItem etc.

So I created a template:

```
<UserControl.Resources>

    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid Width="120" Height="120">
                        <Rectangle Fill="AliceBlue"/>                            
                        <ContentPresenter  Content="{TemplateBinding Property=ContentControl.Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <Button Name="hello"  Content="123" Width="100" Height="100" >
        </Button>
</Grid>
```

Now the ContentPresenter only display the content of the Button, but not include the button itself, how can I include the templated control itself too?